# Cygwin grep, no such file or directory

Tags: windows-7, cygwin, grep

This is the first time I'm using Cygwin and I have not so much experience with scripts.

I'm trying to grep words out of a XML document and need to get them counted. When I press enter I get a message that grep: foo.xml: No such file or directory.

```
emmy@KRIM-PC ~ 
$ grep "original\-recipient\-address>049." foo.xml |wc -l 
grep: foo.xml: No such file or directory 
0
```

I've been googling and reading for hours and I can't understand what's wrong?! 
The file exists and it's located in C:\Users\emmy\Downloads.

Comment: the directory you were in clearly does not have the file in question.  Navigate to that directory from within Cygwin and it will work.

Comment: Without cygwin here grep from [UnxUpdates.zip](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

You write the file is in `C:\Users\emmy\Downloads`. The Cygwin command prompt shows

```
emmy@KRIM-PC ~
```

the `~` is actually your working directory. It means your home directory (probably `/home/emmy/`). Try cd `cd /cygdrive/c/Users/emmy/Downloads` and then run your `grep` command again.